# How to overload ! operator for an enum?

Tags: c#, enums, operator-overloading

My situation is simple.
I have an enum for Direction (4 directions)

```
enum Direction
{
    Left=1,
    Up,
    Right,
    Down
}
```

I want to have `!Direction.Up` return `Direction.Down` and vice versa, and likewise for `Direction.Left` and `Direction.Right`.

How do I achieve this? Or is there a simpler way to do this than thinking about enums and overloading the `!` operator on an enum?

Comment: What is wrong with `value != Direction.Up`?

Comment: @DavidG That returns `true` or `false` not `Direction.Down`.

Comment: I have to do an operation regarding direction, then reverse it. So I need to have Direction, then !Direction, so that it's easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot overload an operator on enums.
What you could do is write an extension method, but you still can't use an operator in that case.

```
public static Direction Not(this Direction direction) {
switch (direction) {
        case Direction.Left: return Direction.Right;
        case Direction.Right: return Direction.Left;
        case Direction.Up: return Direction.Down;
        default: return Direction.Up;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I like that this keeps the original a simple enum and just provides the appropriate method.  I'd probably call it Reverse instead of Not to better describe the functionality.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot overload operators for enumerations.  In order to get that functionality you would need to use a class, instead of an enum, although you can write one that emulates an enumeration conceptually.

```
public class Direction
{
    private Direction() { }
    public static readonly Direction Up = new Direction();
    public static readonly Direction Down = new Direction();
    public static readonly Direction Left = new Direction();
    public static readonly Direction Right = new Direction();

    public static Direction operator !(Direction direction)
    {
        if (direction == Direction.Up)
            return Direction.Down;
        else if (direction == Direction.Down)
            return Direction.Up;
        else if (direction == Direction.Left)
            return Direction.Right;
        else if (direction == Direction.Right)
            return Direction.Left;
        throw new Exception("Unreachable");
    }
}
```

Comment: So would `class Direction{public static int Left=0;}` help, and then I should overload `Direction`? An example would help.

Comment: @kenshin.thebattosai See edit.  Of course if you want it to have a meaningful ToString, Parse, etc. methods you'll need to add them.  This is just a starting place.

Comment: Although this seems to be exactly what you've asked for (+1) I wouldn't attempt to change the semantics of the boolean NOT operator. Even in real life, "not left" does not mean "right". Why not have an `OppositeOf(Direction d)` method with a simple `switch`?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis True, although the negation operator (`~`) could be argued to semantically apply.  Each direction is the "opposite" of the other.

Comment: @Servy yeah "negative left" sounds better :)

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I don't think you can `switch` anything other than bool, char, enum, string, int etc

Comment: @kenshin.thebattosai `case` statements must contain compile time constants.  That is the requirement.

Comment: @kenshin.thebattosai That would use your `enum` rather than a separate class - you would only use the class to allow the use of the ! operator.

Comment: So the class would just be a helper class - with a single public static method returning an enum. Like that mentioned in the other answers, only different from the helper function in that it is used to overload an operator. Yes?

Comment: I'm taking the other answer strictly because it just uses enums, which is what the question (in the title) deals with. I accept that this is a solution which is even more extensible. Thanks - I never thought it possible to create such a class to mirror the functionality and usage (Direction.Up) of the enum type. I'm only wondering why you didn't use `public static readonly int Left=0;` etc which would've allowed for `switch` *and* usage of Enum-like values

Comment: I understood, you can't do that because you're only overloading ! operator for objects of type `Direction`.

Comment: @kenshin.thebattosai It also allows you to write other methods (not just operator overloads) that accepts a `Direction` object as a parameter.  If the values are strictly integers then there's no way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overload operators on enums, enums are meant to store values and nothing else. You'd need to wrap an enum into some higher level abstraction if you want to add any other functionality.

If I were you, I'd just write a function to return opposites, it's the simplest approach.

```
Direction Opposite(Direction original)
{
     switch (original)
     {
          case(Direction.Left): return Direction.Right;
          case(Direction.Right): return Direction.Left;
          case(Direction.Up): return Direction.Down;
          case(Direction.Down): return Direction.Up;
          default: throw new SomeException("Uncovered direction case. Fix your switch.");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
enum Direction
{
    Right=  1,
    Left = -1,
    Up   =  2,
    Down = -2
}
```

And you will use:

```
newDirection = -oldDirection;
```

which mean in the opposite direction. And the meaning of:

```
!oldDirection
```

I will use this,... well for any other direction, just NOT the old.

Comment: Nice one. Didn't think of it this way.